# find Missing Range in a given a range

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

We need to find the missing range when main range is given and all sub ranges are given.
main range :[-10, 10]

sub Ranges: [-10, -5] , [-4, -3], [-2, 3],  [7, 10]

Assumptions:

1) Range values can go upto 2^63.

2)sub ranges wont overlap and their order can be different.
for ex: the can be [-10, -5],[7, 10], [-2, 3], [-4, -3]

what is best algorithm to find the missing range here?

Comment: Do intervals [-10, -5] and [-5, -3] overlap? If not, can we assume that the intervals are (inclusive, exclusive) or (exclusive, inclusive)?

Comment: and are your subRanges sorted?

Comment: Sorry they wont overalap , i will update it.

Comment: @ grodzi subRanges order can be different. for ex: the can be [-10, -5],[ 7, 10], [-2, 3], [-4, -3]

Comment: If the ranges don't overlap and aren't in order, then start by sorting the array so that they *are* in order.

Comment: is it the missing range or the missing range__S__ ?. Your title say singular, your example say plural ([-5,-4], [-3,-2],[3,7]])

Comment: So what have **YOU** tried / researched so far? Share **YOUR** findings.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the intervals are unsorted, I do not see avoiding a sorting cost since each interval can be a singleton (`[n,n]`). That cost can be `O(n log n)` for a comparison sort or `O(n)` for a radix sort. From now on, let's assume that input intervals are sorted and contain no overlaps. Here is a `O(n)` single pass Python implementation:

```
xs =  [[-10, -5] , [-4, -3], [-2, 3], [7, 10]]
bounds = (-10, 10)
missing = list()

# pre-processing
xs_sorted = sorted(xs)

# pre-processing a missing range on the lower bound
if bounds[0] < xs_sorted[0][0]:
  missing.append((bounds[0], xs_sorted[0][0]-1))

def f_reduce(a, b):
  if a[1] + 1 == b[0]:
    # merge contiguous intervals
    return (a[0], b[1])
  else:
    # gap detected; add the gap to the missing range list
    # and move to the next value
    missing.append((a[1]+1, b[0]-1))
    return b

from functools import reduce
reduce(f_reduce, xs_sorted)

# post-processing on a missing range on the upper bound
if bounds[1] > xs_sorted[-1][1]:
  missing.append((xs_sorted[-1][1]+1, bounds[1]))

print(missing)
# [(4, 6)]
```

The approach is to use a functional style `reduce` with a stinky side-effect. When the function `f_reduce` encounters two intervals `(a, b)` and `(c, d)`, we return a compound interval `(a, d)` if `b + 1 == c`. Otherwise, a gap is detected and stored; the returned interval is `(c, d)`. The pre and post processing steps are dealing with nuisance cases when gaps occur on the two extreme ranges of the interval.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following way, it works in O(n) where n is the range width.

```
// entire range is initially 0.
    int arr[range_max - range_min + 2] = {0};
    //for each sub_range increment the values by 1.
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        arr[sub_range_min[i] - range_min] += 1;
        arr[sub_range_min[i] - range_max + 1] -= 1;
    }
    for(int i = 1; i< range_max - range_min + 2; i++){
        arr[i] += arr[i-1];
    }
    // all the uncovered area in the range by the sub_ranges will be marked 0 in the array.
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can pass through array and find index i where

```
xi != y(i-1)
```

Pair

```
(y(i-1), xi)
```

is the answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming only **one** missing interval:

We may do it in O(k) where k is the number of subranges.

Make a chain (like Chasles) of the connected subranges (since they trivially do not overlap).

At the end, three possible cases:

- only one chain: the missing subrange is at the beginning
- or at the end
- two chains: it is in between

At the current subinterval, check if it is a prolongement of a chain.

- if not create another chain.
- if yes, increase the chain, like ssssnake. Then maybe it connects that chain with another one. Then reduce the two chains and the sub interval as a single big chain

A chain may simply be representated with its left and right
And to find the chain to increase, may simply use a hashmap on left and another one on right

```js
function getMissingSub (subs, minRange, maxRange) {
  const chainsByLeft = new Map () // left -> [left, whatsoever]
  const chainsByRight = new Map () // right -> [whatsoever, right]
  // before: [[a, [a, whatsoever]]]
  // after: [[newVal, [newval, whatsoever]]]
  function prolongeLeft (x, newVal) {
    const chain = chainsByLeft.get(x)
    const old = chain[0]
    chain[0] = newVal
    chainsByLeft.set(newVal, chain)
    chainsByLeft.delete(old)
    return chain
  }
  function prolongeRight (x, newVal) {
    const chain = chainsByRight.get(x)
    const old = chain[1]
    chain[1] = newVal
    chainsByRight.set(newVal, chain)
    chainsByRight.delete(old)
    return chain
  }
  subs.forEach(([a,b]) => {
    if (chainsByLeft.has(b) || chainsByRight.has(a)) {
      if (chainsByLeft.has(b)) {
        // prolonge on the left
        const chain = prolongeLeft(b, a)
        if (chainsByRight.has(a) ) {
          prolongeRight(a, chain[1])
        }
      } else {
        const chain = prolongeRight(a, b)
        if (chainsByLeft.has(b) ) {
          prolongeLeft(b, chain[0])
        }
      }
    } else {
      // new chain
      const chain = [a, b]
      chainsByLeft.set(a, chain)
      chainsByRight.set(b, chain)
    }
  })
  let missingRange
  if (chainsByLeft.size === 1) {
    const [, [left, right]] = chainsByLeft.entries().next().value
    if (left === minRange) {
      missingRange = [right, maxRange]
    } else {
      missingRange = [minRange, left]
    }
  } else {
    const [[, [l1, r1]], [, [l2, r2]]] = chainsByLeft.entries()
    if (r1 < r2) {
      missingRange = [r1, l2]
    } else {
      missingRange = [r2, l1]
    }
  }
  return { missingRange, chainsByLeft }
}
const dump = ({ missingRange: [a,b] }) => console.log(`missing [${a}, ${b}]`)
dump(getMissingSub([[0, 1],[1, 2]], 0, 4))
dump(getMissingSub([[0, 1],[1, 2]], -1, 2))
dump(getMissingSub([[0, 1],[2, 3]], 0, 3))
dump(getMissingSub([[-10, -5] , [-4, -3], [-2, 3], [7, 10]], -10, 10))
```

---

If you have several missing ranges, obviously you can have more than two chains, then you may need a sort to order the chains and directly find the gap between consecutive chains

```js
//COPY PASTED FROM BEFORE
function getMissingSub (subs, minRange, maxRange) {
  const chainsByLeft = new Map () // left -> [left, whatsoever]
  const chainsByRight = new Map () // right -> [whatsoever, right]
  // before: [[a, [a, whatsoever]]]
  // after: [[newVal, [newval, whatsoever]]]
  function prolongeLeft (x, newVal) {
    const chain = chainsByLeft.get(x)
    const old = chain[0]
    chain[0] = newVal
    chainsByLeft.set(newVal, chain)
    chainsByLeft.delete(old)
    return chain
  }
  function prolongeRight (x, newVal) {
    const chain = chainsByRight.get(x)
    const old = chain[1]
    chain[1] = newVal
    chainsByRight.set(newVal, chain)
    chainsByRight.delete(old)
    return chain
  }
  subs.forEach(([a,b]) => {
    if (chainsByLeft.has(b) || chainsByRight.has(a)) {
      if (chainsByLeft.has(b)) {
        // prolonge on the left
        const chain = prolongeLeft(b, a)
        if (chainsByRight.has(a) ) {
          prolongeRight(a, chain[1])
        }
      } else {
        const chain = prolongeRight(a, b)
        if (chainsByLeft.has(b) ) {
          prolongeLeft(b, chain[0])
        }
      }
    } else {
      // new chain
      const chain = [a, b]
      chainsByLeft.set(a, chain)
      chainsByRight.set(b, chain)
    }
  })
  let missingRange
  if (chainsByLeft.size === 1) {
    const [, [left, right]] = chainsByLeft.entries().next().value
    if (left === minRange) {
      missingRange = [right, maxRange]
    } else {
      missingRange = [minRange, left]
    }
  } else {
    const [[, [l1, r1]], [, [l2, r2]]] = chainsByLeft.entries()
    if (r1 < r2) {
      missingRange = [r1, l2]
    } else {
      missingRange = [r2, l1]
    }
  }
  return { missingRange, chainsByLeft }
}

//ENDCOYP PASTED

function getMissingSubs(subs, minRange, maxRange) {
  const { missingRange, chainsByLeft } = getMissingSub.apply(null, arguments)
  const missingRanges = []
  ;[[minRange, minRange], ...chainsByLeft.values(), [maxRange, maxRange]]
    .sort((a,b) => a[0]-b[0]).reduce((chain, next) => {
      if (chain[1] !== next[0]) {
        missingRanges.push([chain[1], next[0]])
      }
      return next
    })
  return { missingRanges }
}
const dump2 = ({ missingRanges }) => console.log(`missing2 ${JSON.stringify(missingRanges)}`)
dump2(getMissingSubs([[0, 1],[1, 2]], 0, 4))
dump2(getMissingSubs([[0, 1],[1, 2]], -1, 2))
dump2(getMissingSubs([[0, 1],[2, 3]], 0, 3))
dump2(getMissingSubs([[-10, -5] , [-4, -3], [-2, 3], [7, 10]], -10, 10))
```